# 267 3MW wind turbines can produce 960MW?

Tags: power, energy

**[WINDFARM PROPOSAL](https://majorprojects.accelo.com/public/88c5dc99f4e1e380bed8c42ad0dd8f01/01.%20Liverpool%20Range%20Wind%20-%20Assessment%20Report.pdf)**

In the proposal above, it states that 267 3MW wind turbines are used to provide 960MW. but using a very simple calculation: 267 * 3MW=*801MW*.

So how is it that the windfarm is designed to produced *960MW*?

wind turbines used are **[Vestas V112 Wind Turbine Generators 3MW](https://en.wind-turbine-models.com/turbines/7-vestas-v112-onshore)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They did not use the V112 for power estimate calculations, they used it as a representative turbine for noise estimates. The project assumes a 3.6MW average turbine power to achieve the power rating for the farm.

See page 10 of your report.

Comment: No, the turbines are rated for 3 MW, and the performance curve on the linked page indicates that that is a max number.

Comment: Approximate capacity of 3.6 MW (1)  The project may use a mix of turbine models across the site to better utilise the wind resource profile.  So not based on a single turbine profile. Based on the Siemens turbine installs in ON and MB Canada, the downtime seems significant yet not MTBF data is published.

Comment: And by "page 10" I guess you mean the page with the number "7" written on it.

Comment: Yah, I just looked at the PDF reader page number

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The performance curve on the linked page shows the V112 tops out at 3.07MW. It would need to be ~3.6MW to hit the power rating of the whole project.